# Sort multi-dimentional inner array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, usort

I have been trying to sort multi-dimensional inner array, i have tried  array_multisort() method but doesn't worked in my case.

```
$array = [
        [
            'sizes'=>[
                [
                    'weight'=>25,
                    'height'=>110
                ], [
                    'weight'=>45,
                    'height'=>110
                ],

            ]
        ],
        [
            'sizes'=>[
                [
                    'weight'=>80,
                    'height'=>120
                ],[
                    'weight'=>20,
                    'height'=>120
                ]
                ]

        ]
    ];
```

I need to sort the above array based on weight in such a way that if sort by highest weight array should return sizes block with highest weight and vice-versa. In this case "weight": 80 is the highest and if sort by lowest 1st "weight": 20 should come 1st.

**Expected output after sort for both SORT_ASC and SORT_DESC**

```
 $array = [
        [
            'sizes'=>[
                [
                    'weight'=>80,
                    'height'=>120
                ],[
                    'weight'=>20,
                    'height'=>120
                ]
                ]

        ],
        [
            'sizes'=>[
                [
                    'weight'=>25,
                    'height'=>110
                ], [
                    'weight'=>45,
                    'height'=>110
                ],

                ]
            ]
    ];
```

Comment: You can make helper function that would go through "sizes" subarray and find max (or min) weight. Then use the helper function inside of usort's callback to compare the two values.

Comment: @MichalHynčica can you please give me an example code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_column` to extract the weight values from a sub-array, then  use `max` on those, and then the `<=>` comparison operator to compare those two maxima:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return max(array_column($b['sizes'], 'weight')) <=>
           max(array_column($a['sizes'], 'weight'));
});
```

This would be for descending order, for ascending you would need to switch $a and $b around, resp. multiply with -1.